# Combining and shortening two where clause conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #exclGeoKeys (xKEY INT);
INSERT INTO #exclGeoKeys
    values
    (1),
    (2);

CREATE TABLE #y (NAME CHAR(1),xKEY INT);
INSERT INTO #y
    values
    ('A',1),
    ('C',2),
    ('D',NULL),
    ('E',3),
    ('F',4);
```

Can I shorten the following so it produces the same result and doesn't need the section `OR xKEY IS NULL`?

```
SELECT *
FROM   #y
WHERE  xKEY NOT IN 
                 (
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM #exclGeoKeys
                 ) 
       OR 
       xKEY IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are looking to avoid the LEFT JOIN here?

Comment: The top one is yours, the two below it both return the same result.  Are either what you're looking for?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53789/9

Comment: @Aushin: FYI: if you end each `SELECT` with a semicolon, they will show their result sets separately: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53789/10

Comment: thanks @mellamokb I was wondering how to do that haha

Comment: @Aushin I'm not trying to avoid anything in particular - just have the feeling that the section `OR xKEY IS NULL` can somehow be amalgamated in with the rest of the script using something like `COALESCE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option with NOT [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) operator

```
SELECT *
FROM #y t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM #exclGeoKeys t2
                  WHERE t.xKEY = t2.xKEY
                  )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53789/2)

Option with EXISTS and EXCEPT operators

```
SELECT *
FROM #y t
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT t.xKEY
              EXCEPT
              SELECT t2.xKEY
              FROM #exclGeoKeys t2
              )
```

Option with NOT EXISTS and INTERSECT operators

```
SELECT *
FROM #y t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT t.xKEY
                  INTERSECT
                  SELECT t2.xKEY
                  FROM #exclGeoKeys t2
                  )
```

Comment: +1 thanks - I use this structure quite a bit - this highlights a major difference to `NOT IN`

Comment: would you expect the `NOT EXISTS` to run a lot faster? ...the production script seems to be running in 20secs now - compared to 5mins when using the old where clause?!

Comment: Agreed, I always use EXISTS in the WHERE clause. Gives a good explanation Martin Smith in this post [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists.
Also in answer I added another options of query.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
--USING NOT EXISTS (DOES NOT REQUIRE THE IS NULL SECTION)

SELECT *
FROM #y AS T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #exclGeoKeys AS T2 WHERE T1.xKEY = T2.xKEY) 
--OR T1.xKEY IS NULL;

--USING NOT IN
SELECT *
FROM #y AS T1
WHERE T1.xKEY NOT IN (SELECT T2.xKEY FROM #exclGeoKeys AS T2) 
OR T1.xKEY IS NULL;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Unreal value

```
SELECT *
FROM   #y
WHERE  coalesce(xKEY,-1) NOT IN 
                 (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM #exclGeoKeys
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to use a left join?

```
SELECT #y.*
FROM   #y
LEFT JOIN #exclGeoKeys excl on excl.xKEY = #y.xKEY
WHERE excl.xKEY IS NULL
```